# Icon should appear when button selected (via HTML)

Tags: html, gravity-forms-plugin

Currently when the button is selected, the font goes "Bold" and the dot appears in the spot.

I'd like to make a small icon (a tick) appear also/instead. Or I'm open to any other ideas.

I'm using GravityForm. Here is my site [Click here](http://www.suitsme.net.au/product/single/). I'm talking about the button next to the text "Icon Appear". Here is a screenshot

[image]

Requirement: Icon to appear next to the button when it has been selected/clicked.

Is there a simple way with HTML to achieve this?

Comment: Which button are you talking about ? what is your exact requirement? Specify clearly. Else your question will be closed

Comment: I'm talking about the button next to the text "Icon Appear". If I click it, it goes bold. But I need to make it more obvious so I wanted to make a "tick" appear. Requirement: Icon to appear when the dial has been clicked.

Comment: I can't find any such text *"Icon Appear"*. Kindly share the image here

Comment: My apologies- my site had a waiting page up. I've turned it off (temporarily). Thanks

Comment: I can't find any such "Icon Appear" text too.

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](http://www.suitsme.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Screenshot.jpg)

Comment: Using just HTML? That's a definite no-no

Comment: Ok thanks. It doesn't have to just be HTML, and if someone can think of another way to make the "selection" obvious- I'm open to ideas

Answer (score 0):

css way.UPDATED

```css
.tick{margin-left:5px;visibility:hidden}

input[type=radio]:checked + span{visibility:visible;}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="suit"/><span class="tick">Selected <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/matiasam/ios7-style/16/Clear-Tick-icon.png" /></span>
<input type="radio" name="suit"/><span class="tick">Selected <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/matiasam/ios7-style/16/Clear-Tick-icon.png" /></span>
```

Comment: I've pasted this into the CSS of my theme but it hasn't worked. I think I'm missing something basic. Also it's for "radio" buttons (not tick's). Thanks tho

Comment: Still not quite working- I've pasted the CSS into my Theme's Custom CSS. I've added the HTML to the place I actually want to see the code. But all I see is two dot's now... Have a look [here](http://www.suitsme.net.au/product/single/)

Comment: can't see any dots or suits ? have you changed the page since yesterday ?

Comment: Nope- I put up the "coming soon" page (which overides the site). Could you please look now- I've re-opened the site.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use below code :

```
label > img {display: none;}
input[type=radio]:checked + label > img{display:inline-block;}
```

For prevent global impact, use classes / ids accordingly like...

```
#section label > img {display: none;}
#section input[type=radio]:checked + label > img{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by class? If I understand correct- that is putting "<div> class name .... </div>" ? And I post your code in the CSS?

Comment: u can use the same code in your css. but it is currently reflect globally. Only for this I am saying use classes like lable.classname > img{} etc.

Comment: I've added `.ticker > img {display: none;} input[type=radio]:checked + label > img{display:inline-block;}` to my theme's custom CSS. I've placed this next to my images (where the html goes). It did not work. ''. `<div class="ticker"> #ticker > https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fugue/icon_shadowless/tick-circle-frame.png {display: none;} #section input[type=radio]:checked + label > img{display:inline-block;} </div>`